# full_join() not working properly after gsub() call - duplicate rows produced in prduct

Tags: r, tidyr

Goal: merge FIPS codes into county data for US county map

I am trying to merge the fips codes for the `countypop` dataset from the `usmaps` package with a set of county demographic data here: https://www.kaggle.com/etsc9287/2020-general-election-polls so that I can use the `plot_usmap()` function to get some nice plots off.

However, I have encountered minor formatting issues which impede normal join functions. In countypop dataset, the county column usually has the word "County" at the end of it, while the Kaggle datset does not. I've solved this issue using the `gsub()` function, but I can't get the two datasets to join through `full_join()`. Here is the code I used to get rid of the "County" instances from the countypop dataset. I also changed the `abbr` column to `state`.

```
library(usmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
localCounty <- data.frame(countypop)
localCounty$county <- gsub("county", "", localCounty$county, ignore.case=TRUE)
localCounty$state <- localCounty$abbr
localCounty$abbr <- NULL
```

To get the data from Kaggle in, I ran the following code (I had to download the files first):

```
election <- read.csv("data/dataFresh.csv")
View(election)
dim(election)
election <- na.omit(election)
```

I got rid of all the NA values because there are many non-county rows in the dataset.

When I execute a `full_join()`, for some reason the rows don't actually merge. I was using `inner_join()` initially, but then wasn't getting any visible results so I switch to `full_join()` so I could see the issue. I ran the below code to join my two datasets:

```
countyFIPS <- full_join(localCounty, election, by = c("county","state"))
```

However, after joining for some reason the matching counties and states did not merge, and I have two rows for each county. Regarding the image, I sorted by county name to check for duplicates.
[image]

Solution: turns out there was an extra space before "County", the extra space was causing the merge to fail

Comment: The first thing I'd check is whitespace around one or other of your join columns in one or other of your data frames. Most likely the csv from Kaggle.  I can't check that from your screenshot.  That's one of the many reasons why `dput()` or similar is better than a screenshot....  Yes:  `localCounty$county <- gsub("county", "", localCounty$county, ignore.case=TRUE)`.  I reckon you've got trailing spaces...

Comment: Ah right, I just checked it and there was an extra space. Man, what a rookie mistake! Thank you for the help, I changed my gsub to " County" instead.